# How do you designate where a Scheduled Task is created?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

Is there an option in possibly SCHTASKS to define where a scheduled job is actually created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the `SCHTASKS` I would recommend to use the .Net wrapper around the COM class `TaskScheduler`, throught which you can interact with the Windows Task Scheduler. It required a bit more code but offers a rich set of properties and good control of the tasks. Doing so can use `ITaskFolder` to create folders for your task(s). I include som of the code I use below (which will create a task called "MyTaskName" in the folder "MyTaskFolder". Also check out [this article for good information on the subject](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx).

```
    TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler scheduler = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
    scheduler.Connect(null, null, null, null); //run as current user.

    ITaskDefinition taskDef = scheduler.NewTask(0);
    taskDef.RegistrationInfo.Author = task.TaskAuthor;
    ...

    ITimeTrigger trigger = (ITimeTrigger)taskDef.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_TIME);
    ...

    IExecAction action = (IExecAction)taskDef.Actions.Create(_TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC);
    ...

    ITaskFolder root = scheduler.GetFolder("\\");
    root.CreateFolder("MyTaskFolder");      //// here

    IRegisteredTask regTask = root.RegisterTaskDefinition(
        "MyTaskName",
        taskDef,
        (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        null, // user
        null, // password
        _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, //User must already be logged on. The task will be run only in an existing interactive session.
        "" //SDDL
        );
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the folder already exists. Ypu can get the available folders using

```
ITaskFolderCollection folders = root.GetFolders(0);
```

Comment: `TaskScheduler` is not really a .Net class. It's COM class that you can use from .Net.

Comment: MSDN expresses it as a class, look at the topic "TaskScheduler Class" of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx . You might be rights that its only a wrapper around a COM object, but I don't think its that obvious whether it is a class or not.

Comment: that's completely different class! Notice that, for example, it doesn't have the `Connect()` method. The `TaskScheduler` you use in your code is actually an implementation of the COM interface [`ITaskService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832.aspx).

Comment: Aoouch, you are so right, im so wrong. Linking to the wrong class is embarrassing, at least... :( I'll update the answer to reflect on your input. And +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a path name in the task name string (`/TN` parameter). For instance, `/TN Foo\Bar` will create a task named Bar in the Foo folder.